# SQL Update multiple values with a group by statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tried checking similar posts but just cannot get this thing right, please help.

This query returns the correct data but the update statement complains because it says more than

```
SELECT 
    classificationchartofaccountname, 
    -SUM(ISNULL(HLD.Nominal, 0))  AS 'Total' 
FROM
    [dbsFPM].[dbo].[rpt_Holdings] HLD 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbsFPM].[dbo].[rpt_FundAccounts] FA ON HLD.Username = FA.Username 
                                         AND HLD.ClientPortfolioCode = FA.ClientPortfolioCode 
                                         AND FA.ClassificationChartOfAccountName = HLD.InstrumentName 
WHERE 
    HLD.username =  @username 
    AND FA.Username = @username 
    AND FA.Narration = 'IncomeStatement' 
    AND FA.AccountType = 'Expense'  
GROUP BY 
    ClassificationChartOfAccountName)
```

RETURNS:

```
classificationchartofaccountname    Total

General Expenses on ZAR 17578.38

lc Audit 2014 on ZAR    6533.12

lc Trustee Fees - Other on ZAR  840.41

lc Trustee Fees-ZAR 38524.34

Management Fees-ZAR 6452680.040

Performance Fees-ZAR    175.80
```

The update statement i want to use errors out as follows:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Here is the update:

```
UPDATE [rpt_FundAccounts]
SET ReconNarration = 'ExpenseAnalysis_Period', 
    Recon = (SELECT -SUM(ISNULL(HLD.Nominal, 0)) 
             FROM [dbo].[rpt_Holdings] HLD 
             INNER JOIN [dbo].[rpt_FundAccounts] FA ON HLD.Username = FA.Username 
                                                    AND HLD.ClientPortfolioCode = FA.ClientPortfolioCode 
                                                    AND FA.ClassificationChartOfAccountName = HLD.InstrumentName 
             WHERE HLD.username =  @Username 
               AND FA.Username = @Username 
               AND FA.Narration = 'IncomeStatement' 
               AND FA.AccountType = 'Expense' 
               /* and ClassificationChartOfAccountName = 'Management Fees-ZAR'*/ 
             GROUP BY ClassificationChartOfAccountName)
WHERE 
    username = @username  
    AND Narration = 'IncomeStatement' 
    AND AccountType = 'Expense' 
    /*and ClassificationChartOfAccountName = 'Management Fees-ZAR' */
```

The issue is i want to update all the `ClassificationChartOfAccountNames` with their respective totals from `[rpt_Holdings]`

Please help, sorry I am still a beginner!

```
ClassificationChartOfAccountName

Bank Charge Fees on GBP
Bank_Interest Charges on ZAR
Distribution Paid
Expenses
Foreign Withholding Tax
General Expenses on EUR
General Expenses on USD
General Expenses on ZAR
lc Audit 2012 on ZAR
lc Audit 2013 Final on ZAR
lc Audit 2013 on ZAR
lc Audit 2014 on ZAR
lc Scrip - SBSA on ZAR
lc Trustee Fees - Other on ZAR
lc Trustee Fees-ZAR
Management Fees-ZAR
Performance Fees-ZAR
Realised Foreign Exchange Gain
Realised GainLoss
Realised Pull To Par
```

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Use update as UPDATE FA

Comment: The proposed answer just leads to multi-part identifier could not be bound and if i add the join back then it looks no different to what i had.      What works is to have a where statement that contains a where for each specific ClassificationChartofAccountName but this just seems like a really bad idea doing it say 20 times the same statement with just a different hard coded ClassificationChartofAccountName and also will not pick up any new ClassificationChartofAccountNam. So unfortnately stilll stuck

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is in the `GROUP BY` statement in the subquery. It makes it output not one SUM value but a table with SUMs for each `ClassificationChartOfAccountName`. But you can't update a scalar value with a TABLE and you get the error - `Subquery returned more than 1 value`

If you want to update table with SUMs according row's `ClassificationChartOfAccountName` you should make a link between updated table row and a subquery. So subquery outputs only one value.
I think it should be something like:

```
UPDATE [rpt_FundAccounts] FA 
SET ReconNarration = 'ExpenseAnalysis_Period', 
    Recon = (select -sum(isnull(HLD.Nominal,0)) 
             from [dbo].[rpt_Holdings] HLD 
             WHERE  HLD.Username =  FA.Username 
                    and HLD.ClientPortfolioCode = FA.ClientPortfolioCode 
                    and FA.ClassificationChartOfAccountName = HLD.InstrumentName
             )
WHERE username = @username  
      and Narration = 'IncomeStatement' 
      and AccountType = 'Expense'
```

Comment: The proposed answer just leads to multi-part identifier could not be bound and if i add the join back then it looks no different to what i had. What works is to have a where statement that contains a where for each specific ClassificationChartofAccountName but this just seems like a really bad idea doing it say 20 times the same statement with just a different hard coded ClassificationChartofAccountName and also will not pick up any new ClassificationChartofAccountNam. So unfortnately stilll stuck

Comment: @Newby101 You don't have to add you join back to this statement. Here `FA` alias is the updated table `[rpt_FundAccounts]` (look at the first line).

Comment: "The Multi-Part Identifier could not be bound.

Comment: @Newby101: Check if all fields names you used in the query have aliases you used to identify them. For example if you use JOIN then fields from both tables can have the same name in this case you have to use an alias as in the following example: `HLD.Username =  FA.Username `